# Understanding how to escape nested double quotes in JSON

Tags: json

*I've found this before, but it seems Google doesn't want me to find the answer... so I'm asking it here.
*

## Can someone please explain to me the "pattern" I need to follow when dealing with nested double quotes in JSON code?

**As in:**

- For the first quotes, you don't need to escape them
- The the 2nd layer, you need 1 backslash
- For the 3rd layer, you need 3 backslashes
- For the 4th layer, you need X backslashes
- For the 5th layer, you need Y backslashes

## How does this progress?  What's the formula?

- How many slashes do I need if I'm 9 layers down?

Many thanks!

Been googling for 15 minutes, about to put my fist through my computer screen.
I found a page that clearly defined this before... can't find it now.

Comment: Why aren't you using an existing library that has already been written, tested and debugged?

Comment: Because I'm not in a traditional development environment.

Comment: I suggest you can still turn to them and use code from them as well as learn about the questions you're asking.